# WiX Installer creates two menu items in the Start Menu for a shortcut

Tags: wix, shortcut

Below is the code I use to create a Start Menu shortcut for my program using the WiX Toolset to create an installer for my program.

```
<DirectoryRef Id="ApplicationProgramsFolder">
  <Component Id="VDiskShortcut" Guid="">
    <File Id="VDiskExe" DiskId="1" Source="..\..\..\bin\vdisk.exe"/>
     <Shortcut Id="VDiskStartMenuShortcut" 
         Name="Virtual Disk" Show="minimized"
         Description="Virtual Disk"
         Target="[#VDiskExe]"
         WorkingDirectory="MYBIN"/>
    <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\Microsoft\VDisk" Name="installed" Type="integer" Value="1" KeyPath="yes"/>
  </Component>
</DirectoryRef>
```

When I install my program I find that there are two menu items created on the Start Menu. One is called "Virtual Disk" and the other is called "vdisk.exe". Why does the WiX installer do this? Is it because that is the name of the program in the Target element? If that is the case how do I specify a name of the shortcut without getting it mixed up with the name of the target? I want only one Menu item in the Start Menu and its name should be the Name I specify on the Shortcut Element in WiX, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You should show more of your source. The component might be in two separate features, and it might be an issue that the guid isn't "*". Does the MSI file have multiple entries for this in the Shortcut table, and which component(s) do they refer to?

Comment: The component is in two features, one is a sub-feature of the other, but when I changed that to make it so that the component is in its own Feature, just one, it didn't change the result, so I don't think that is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing two items in the start menu because you are installing two items under the ProgramMenuFolder: one exe, and one shortcut to it.

Note that the Directory attribute of the Shortcut element allows you to install a shortcut to a location other than the primary location of its component. So one approach to addressing this could be to target the component at  `APPLICATIONROOTDIRECTORY` (or similar - is that `MYBIN` for you?) instead of the `ApplicationProgramsFolder`. This will install vdisk.exe under the ProgramFilesFolder instead of the ProgramMenuFolder so it won't appear in the start menu. Then specify `Directory="ApplicationProgramsFolder"` on the shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by following the example in the FireGiant WiX Tutorial. It worked but I still get a warning message from light when I build my installer. The warning message is

```
warning LGHT1076: ICE69: Mismatched component reference. 
Entry 'VDiskStartMenuShortcut' of the Shortcut table belongs to
component 'VDiskShortcut'. However, the formatted string in column 'Target'
references file 'vdisk.exe' which belongs to component 'vdisk.exe'.
Components are in the same feature.
```

The result is what I want, so I guess I am willing to live with the warning message.